# Usage of Times Used in Comparison

Tags: word-meaning, phrase-meaning

> - three times as long as sth
> - three times longer than sth
> - three times the length of sth

Do the three above mean the same?

Editor of OECD told me that these 3 expressions mean the same. I am confused.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Let us assume that the length being referred to is one meter. As I understand it:

Twice as long as one meter is two meters, and
three times as long as one meter is three meters.

Once longer than one meter is two meters (although not idiomatic).
Twice longer than one meter is three meters, and
three times longer than one meter is four meters.

Twice the length of one meter is two meters, and
three times the length is three meters.

So I would understand examples one and three to mean the same thing. Example two is the exception.